# How can I make this loop more efficient?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a historical collection of ~ 500k loans, some of which have defaulted, others have not.  My dataframe is `lcd_temp`.  `lcd_temp` has information on the loan size (`loan_amnt`), if loan has defaulted or not (`Total Defaults`), annual loan rate (`clean_rate`),term of loan (`clean_term`), and months from origination to default (`mos_to_default`).  `mos_to_default` is equal to `clean_term` if no default.

I would like to calculate the Cumulative Cashflow [`cum_cf`] for each loan as the sum of all coupons paid until default plus (1-severity) if loan defaults, and simply the `loan_amnt` if it pays back on time.

Here's my code, which takes an awful long time to run:

```
severity = 1

for i in range (0,len(lcd_temp['Total_Defaults'])-1):
    if (lcd_temp.loc[i,'Total_Defaults'] ==1):
    # Default, pay coupon only until time of default, plus (1-severity)
        lcd_temp.loc[i,'cum_cf'] = ((lcd_temp.loc[i,'mos_to_default'] /12)  * lcd_temp.loc[i,'clean_rate'])+(1 severity)*lcd_temp.loc[i,'loan_amnt']
    else: 
    # Total cf is sum of coupons (non compounded) + principal 
        lcd_temp.loc[i,'cum_cf'] = (1+lcd_temp.loc[i,'clean_term']/12* lcd_temp.loc[i,'clean_rate'])*lcd_temp.loc[i,'loan_amnt']
```

Any thoughts or suggestions on improving the speed (which takes over an hour so far) welcomed!

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Did you profile it to see where the time is going?

Comment: You can (probably should, if it takes over an hour) use numpy for this, and then select between the two use cases with a mask, e.g. `mask = lcd_temp.loc[..., 'Total_Defaults'] == 1`.

Comment: OP: are you using Pandas? @Evert: why do you believe the `[pandas]` tag is not appropriate?

Comment: @LevLevitsky I don't see any indication of a pandas import, nor any use of a pandas namespace. For all I know, the OP is using normal classes, lists and dicts.

Comment: I think, if you are using python 2.6 or above, then `multiprocessing` is available to you. It seems to me that you could split your data set into a number of chunks, one per core, and pass each chunk to a process and write the results back after all chunks have been calculated.

Comment: @GlennBlasius In your code I don't see anything which make this too much latent.. `1 hour` is huge, you might have to add more information here like.. what is your data frame? is this the simple calculation or any other operation happening?

Comment: @Evert the question mentions a dataframe, which in Python means Pandas. Things like `lcd_temp.loc` in the question also show that OP is using Pandas, not standard Python data structures.

Comment: Sorry for delay, yes, using Pandas.   The import occured in another cell not included in my code.  Apologies.   And thanks to unutbu below for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using Pandas/NumPy, the standard way to replace an `if-then` construction such as the one you are using is to use [`np.where(mask, A, B)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). The `mask` is an array of boolean values. When True, the corresponding value from `A` is returned. When False, the corresponding value from `B` is returned. The result is an array of the same shape as `mask` with values from `A` and/or `B`.

```
severity = 1

mask = (lcd_temp['Total_Defaults'] == 1)
A = (((lcd_temp['mos_to_default'] /12) * lcd_temp['clean_rate'])
     + (1 severity)*lcd_temp['loan_amnt'])
B = (1+lcd_temp['clean_term']/12 * lcd_temp['clean_rate'])*lcd_temp['loan_amnt']

lcd_temp['cum_cf'] = np.where(mask, A, B)
```

---

Notice that this performs the calculation on whole columns instead of row-by-row. This improves performance greatly because it gives Pandas/NumPy the opportunity to pass larger arrays of values to fast underlying C/Fortran functions (in this case, to perform the arithmetic). When you work row-by-row, you are performing scalar arithmetic inside a Python loop, which gives NumPy zero chance to shine.
If you had to compute row-by-row, you would be just as well (and maybe better) off using plain Python.

Even though `A` and `B` computes the values for the entire column -- and some values are not used in the final result returned by `np.where` -- this is still faster than computing row-by-row assuming there are more than a trivial number of rows.

Comment: Tnx, I'll check this out and revert.    Didn't know about mask - nor about the efficiency difference with Numpy (I'm a Newbie).